# scikit's GridSearch and Python in general are not freeing memory

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn

I made some weird observations that my GridSearches keep failing after a couple of hours and I initially couldn't figure out why. I monitored the memory usage then over time and saw that it it started with a few gigabytes (~6 Gb) and kept increasing until it crashed the node when it reached the max. 128 Gb the hardware can take. 
I was experimenting with random forests for classification of a large number of text documents. For simplicity -- to figure out what's going on -- I went back to naive Bayes.

The versions I am using are

- Python 3.4.2
- scikit-learn 0.15.2

I found some related discussion on the scikit-issue list on GitHub about this topic: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/565 and
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/770

And it sounds like it was already successfully addressed!

So, the relevant code that I am using is

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, 
                           parameters, 
                           n_jobs=1, # 
                           cv=5, 
                           scoring='roc_auc',
                           verbose=2,
                           pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs',
                           refit=False)  # tried both True and False

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)  
print('Best score: {0}'.format(grid_search.best_score_))  
print('Best parameters set:')
```

Just out of curiosity, I later decided to do the grid search the quick & dirty way via nested for loop

```
for p1 in parameterset1:
    for p2 in parameterset2:
        ...
            pipeline = Pipeline([
                        ('vec', CountVectorizer(
                                   binary=True,
                                   tokenizer=params_dict[i][0][0],
                                   max_df=params_dict[i][0][1],
                                   max_features=params_dict[i][0][2],
                                   stop_words=params_dict[i][0][3],
                                   ngram_range=params_dict[i][0][4],)),
                         ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(
                                      norm=params_dict[i][0][5],
                                      use_idf=params_dict[i][0][6],
                                      sublinear_tf=params_dict[i][0][7],)),
                         ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

            scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(
                                        estimator=pipeline,
                                        X=X_train, 
                                        y=y_train, 
                                        cv=5, 
                                        scoring='roc_auc',
                                        n_jobs=1)

           params_dict[i][1] = '%s,%0.4f,%0.4f' % (params_dict[i][1], scores.mean(), scores.std())
           sys.stdout.write(params_dict[i][1] + '\n')
```

So far so good. The grid search runs and writes the results to stdout. However, after some time it exceeds the memory cap of 128 Gb again. Same problem as with the GridSearch in scikit. After some experimentation, I finally found out that

```
gc.collect()
len(gc.get_objects()) # particularly this part!
```

in the for loop solves the problem and the memory usage stays constantly at 6.5 Gb over the run time of ~10 hours.

Eventually, I got it to work with the above fix, however, I am curious to hear your ideas about what might be causing this issue and your tips & suggestions!

Comment: That is extremely weird. Could you please file a new issue on github including a script that reproduces the issues using randomly generated data (or even constant data, e.g. `np.ones(shape=(n_samples, n_features), dtype=np.float)`)?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I uploaded some code that caused this issue to https://github.com/rasbt/bugreport/tree/master/scikit-learn/gridsearch_memory and opened an issue here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3973. Thanks!

Comment: In the past, I have also found that some things in sklearn (usually with a random forest) consume too much memory. Depending on the problem, I've had to work around it.  One comment is that for tfidf/document problems a GradientBoostingClassifier may give better results than a RandomForest.  Also, I'm pretty sure the tfidf transformer will return a sparse matrix(todo: make sure of this for your version)...so you need to update your sklearn because RandomForest in 0.15.2 does not support sparse inputs.

Comment: How did you use `gc.collect()` and `len(gc.get_objects())` in `GridSearchCV()` approach to solve it? That approach won't have loops right and hence, no place to put the 2 lines you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

RandomForest in 0.15.2 does not support sparse inputs.

Upgrade sklearn and try again...hopefully this will allow the multiple copies that end up being made to consume way less memory. (and speed things up)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I was using the toarray() call to transform the sparse arrays into dense arrays which is surely very expensive. However, this problem also occurred with a "cheap" naive Bayes or logistic regression classifier (Sgd). Somehow there was a problem with the garbage collection. I should try it again some time with Python 3.4.3  and scikit-learn version 0.16.1

Comment: I believe NB and LR support sparse inputs too.  you could try changing pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs' to just a value of 1

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your exact code, but I faced similar problem nowadays.
It is worth a try.
The similar memory blow-up easily could happen when we copy values from a mutable array or list like object to an other variable creating a copy of the original one and then we modify the new array or list with append or something similar increasing the size of it and the same time increasing the original object too in the background.

So this is an exponential process, so after some time we are out of memory. I was be able to and maybe you can avoid this kind of phenomenon with `deepcopy()` the original object at a value passing.

I had the similar problem, I blew-up the memory with a similar process, then I managed to stay at 10% memory load.

**UPDATE:**
Now I see the snippet of the code with pandas DataFrame. There would be such a valuecopy issue easily.

Comment: I have to take a look at the scikit-learn codebase again, but I am pretty sure that there are a lot of copies internally (in the estimators) going on for safety reasons. However, at some point they should be "garbage collected & disposed" and when I used the `gc.collect()
len(gc.get_objects())` it magically worked. I have to try it some time on future again to see if it was specific to the architecture or Python version

Comment: I would try at least at the pandas df value passing, but anyway good luck.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with GridSearch sir, but I'd suggest when memory and huge lists are an issue write a small custom generator. It can be reused for all your items, just use one that takes any list.  If implementing beyond the lower solution here first read this article, best generator article I've found. I typed it all in and went piece by piece, any questions you have after reading it I can try too

https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/

Don't need:
`for p1 in parameterset1:`

Try

```
 def listerator(this_list):
    i = 0
    while True:
       yield this_list[i]
       i += 1
```

The 'yield' word (anywhere in the declaration) makes this a generator, not a regular function. This runs through and says i equals 0, while True I gotta do stuff, they want me to yield this_list[0], here you go I'll wait for you at `i += 1` if you need me again. The next time it is called, it picks up and does `i += 1`, and notices it's still in a while loop and gives this_list[1], and records its location (`i += 1` again...it will wait there until called again). Notice as I feed it the list once and make a generator (x here), it will exhaust your list.

```
In [141]: x = listerator([1,2,3])

In [142]: next(x)
Out[142]: 1

In [143]: next(x)
Out[143]: 2

In [144]: next(x)
Out[144]: 3

In [148]: next(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-5e4e57af3a97> in <module>()
----> 1 next(x)

<ipython-input-139-ed3d6d61a17c> in listerator(this_list)
      2     i = 0
      3     while True:
----> 4             yield this_list[i]
      5             i += 1
      6 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Let's see if we can use it in a for:

```
In [221]: for val in listerator([1,2,3,4]):
   .....:     print val
   .....:     
1
2
3
4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-221-fa4f59138165> in <module>()
----> 1 for val in listerator([1,2,3,4]):
      2     print val
      3 

<ipython-input-220-263fba1d810b> in listerator(this_list, seed)
      2         i = seed or 0
      3         while True:
----> 4             yield this_list[i]
      5             i += 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Nope. Let's try to handle that:

```
def listerator(this_list):
   i = 0
   while True:
       try:
           yield this_list[i]
       except IndexError:
           break
       i += 1

In [223]: for val in listerator([1,2,3,4]):
    print val
   .....:     
1
2
3
4
```

That works. Now it won't blindly try to return a list element even if it isn't there. From what you said, I can almost guarantee you'll need to be able to seed it (pick up from a certain place, or start freshly from a certain place):

```
def listerator(this_list, seed=None):
   i = seed or 0
   while True:
       try:
           yield this_list[i]
       except IndexError:
           break
       i += 1

In [150]: l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

In [151]: x = listerator(l, 8)

In [152]: next(x)
Out[152]: 9

In [153]: next(x)
Out[153]: 10

In [154]: next(x)
Out[154]: 11
```

`i = seed or 0` is a thing that looks for seed, but seed defaults to None so will usually just start at the logical place, 0, the beginning of the list

How can you use this beast without using (almost) any memory?

```
parameterset1 = [1,2,3,4]
parameterset2 = ['a','b','c','d']

In [224]: for p1 in listerator(parameterset1):
    for p2 in listerator(parameterset2):
        print p1, p2
   .....:         
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
2 a
2 b
2 c
2 d
3 a
3 b
3 c
3 d
4 a
4 b
4 c
4 d
```

that looks familiar huh? Now you can process a trillion values one by one, picking important ones to write to disk, and never blowing up your system. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I know how to use generators, however this was more about a potential platform specific bug I wanted to discuss. Sure, you could use a HashingVectorizer and SGD classifier for streaming data; but for Tf-idfs to be calculated correctly, you need to have access to the whole vocabulary

Comment: Ya,  I noticed after I finished it probably wouldn't help, gotta read the question slower, but glad you solved it