# GPU ran out of memory. How to invoke garbage collector for cleaning the GPU memory at each combination of hyperparameters using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory-management, gpu

I am training my model on a remote server using `GridSearchCV` API for tuning some hyper parameters such as `epochs`, `l_rate`, `batch_size` and `patience`. Unfortunately while tuning them, after few iterations, I get the following error:

```
Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

It seems that [the GPU memory of the server is not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40389498/17082611) and [this error raises when GPU memory is full](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/issues/38#issuecomment-223793214) and they recommend to reduce the data set size and/or the `batch_size`.

Firstly I reduced the `batch_size` to `2`, `4`, `8` and `16` but the error persists since I get:

```
W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:485] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran 
out of memory trying to allocate 1.17GiB (rounded to 1258291200) requested 
by op _EagerConst
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable
'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation
```

Then, I set `os.environ['TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR'] = 'cuda_malloc_async'` as suggested but the problems persists.

Nevertheless the issue seems to be solved if I reduce the data set size, but *I have to use the whole data set* (I cannot waste data).

In order to handle this problem my key ideas are:

1. Prevent a new model and related objects for loss and training management from being recreated. This would be the optimal solution, as it would always use the same model (obviously ensuring that it is "reset" with each new combination of hyperparameters), with relative loss and training. This solution is perhaps the most complicated, as I don't know if the libraries I chose to use allow it.
2. Verify that the same problem is not caused by the data instead of the model (i.e. I would not want the same data to be reallocated for each combination of hyperparameters, leaving the old ones in memory). This could also be a cause and the solution to which I believe is simpler than the previous or similar one, but I see it as less probable as a cause. In any case, check that this does not happen.
3. Reset the memory at each combination of hyperparameters by invoking the garbage collector (I don't know if it works on the GPU too). This is the easiest solution and perhaps the first thing I would try, but it doesn't necessarily work, because if the libraries it uses maintain references to the objects in memory (even if they are no longer used) these are not eliminated by the garbage collector.

Also, [with the tensorflow backend the current model is not destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047606/17082611), so I need to clear the session.

If you have any additional thoughts or ideas, please feel free to share them with me. These are the involved functions:

```
def grid_search_vae(x_train, latent_dimension):
    param_grid = {
        'epochs': [2500],
        'l_rate': [10 ** -4, 10 ** -5, 10 ** -6, 10 ** -7],
        'batch_size': [32, 64],  # [2, 4, 8, 16] won't fix the issue
        'patience': [30]
    }

    ssim_scorer = make_scorer(my_ssim, greater_is_better=True)

    grid = GridSearchCV(
        VAEWrapper(encoder=Encoder(latent_dimension), decoder=Decoder()),
        param_grid, scoring=ssim_scorer, cv=5, refit=False
    )

    grid.fit(x_train, x_train)
    return grid

def refit(fitted_grid, x_train, y_train, latent_dimension):    
    best_epochs = fitted_grid.best_params_["epochs"]
    best_l_rate = fitted_grid.best_params_["l_rate"]
    best_batch_size = fitted_grid.best_params_["batch_size"]
    best_patience = fitted_grid.best_params_["patience"]

    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2)

    encoder = Encoder(latent_dimension)
    decoder = Decoder()
    vae = VAE(encoder, decoder, best_epochs, best_l_rate, best_batch_size)
    vae.compile(Adam(best_l_rate))

    early_stopping = EarlyStopping("val_loss", patience=best_patience)
    history = vae.fit(x_train, x_train, best_batch_size, best_epochs,
                      validation_data=(x_val, x_val), callbacks=[early_stopping])
    return history, vae
```

While this is the `main` code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = load_data("data", "labels")

    # Reducing data set size will fix the issue 
    # new_size = 200
    # x_train, y_train = reduce_size(x_train, y_train, new_size)
    # x_test, y_test = reduce_size(x_test, y_test, new_size)

    latent_dimension = 25 
    grid = grid_search_vae(x_train, latent_dimension)
    history, vae = refit(grid, x_train, y_train, latent_dimension)
```

Can you help me?

If you need this information, these are the GPUs:

```
2023-09-18 11:21:25.628286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1639] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7347 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2023-09-18 11:21:25.629120: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1639] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 7371 MB memory:  -> device: 1, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2023-09-18 11:21:31.911969: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:432] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
```

and I am using tensorflow as keras backend, that is:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.backend()  # 'tensorflow'
```

I also tried to add:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

in the `main` code (as first instructions) but this didn't help.

If you need the code for models, here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.initializers import he_uniform
from keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Reshape, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from keras.src.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from tensorflow import keras

class VAEWrapper:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.vae = VAE(**kwargs)
        self.vae.compile(Adam())

    def fit(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        self.vae.fit(x, y, **kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        return self.vae.get_config()

    def get_params(self, deep):
        return self.vae.get_params(deep)

    def set_params(self, **params):
        return self.vae.set_params(**params)


class VAE(keras.Model, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, epochs=None, l_rate=None, batch_size=None, patience=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.epochs = epochs  # For grid search
        self.l_rate = l_rate  # For grid search
        self.batch_size = batch_size  # For grid search
        self.patience = patience  # For grid search
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="reconstruction_loss")
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        _, _, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        outputs = self.decoder(z)
        return outputs

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        data, labels = data
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

            # Compute losses
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Compute gradient
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))

        # Update metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def test_step(self, data):
        data, labels = data
        # Forward pass
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

        # Compute losses
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.reduce_sum(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
            )
        )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Update metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Encoder(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, latent_dimension):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dimension

        seed = 42

        self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                            kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn1 = BatchNormalization()

        self.conv2 = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                            kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn2 = BatchNormalization()

        self.conv3 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                            kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn3 = BatchNormalization()

        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dense = Dense(units=100, activation="relu")

        self.z_mean = Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_mean")
        self.z_log_var = Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_log_var")

        self.sampling = sample

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        z_mean = self.z_mean(x)
        z_log_var = self.z_log_var(x)
        z = self.sampling(z_mean, z_log_var)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Decoder(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = Dense(units=4096, activation="relu")
        self.bn1 = BatchNormalization()

        self.dense2 = Dense(units=1024, activation="relu")
        self.bn2 = BatchNormalization()

        self.dense3 = Dense(units=4096, activation="relu")
        self.bn3 = BatchNormalization()

        seed = 42

        self.reshape = Reshape((4, 4, 256))
        self.deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn4 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="same",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn5 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn6 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv4 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn7 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv5 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn8 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv6 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=2, activation="sigmoid", padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.reshape(x)
        x = self.deconv1(x)
        x = self.bn4(x)
        x = self.deconv2(x)
        x = self.bn5(x)
        x = self.deconv3(x)
        x = self.bn6(x)
        x = self.deconv4(x)
        x = self.bn7(x)
        x = self.deconv5(x)
        x = self.bn8(x)
        decoder_outputs = self.deconv6(x)
        return decoder_outputs
```

Comment: Did you try a `batch_size` value equal to 16 or 8?

Comment: @MarcoParola Ciao Marco... check my post, I edited it with further information. Grazie!

Comment: okei thanks! Since it is a very quick trial.. can you try 4 and 2 too?

Comment: @MarcoParola I get the same error.

Comment: what if you write the following snippet at the beginning of your script? 
`import os
os.environ[‘TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR’] = ‘cuda_malloc_async’
print(os.getenv(‘TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR’))`

Comment: Oh sorry, in the main function should be okei

Comment: @MarcoParola I get the same error. By the way, I added a bounty reward on this question.

Comment: Could this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75660072/15262384 from another question be helpful for you? It suggest to run a separate process for every model run. So in your case a new process for every combination

Comment: @Jonas How am I supposed to edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

To tackle your memory issue try:

Clearing GPU memory:
TensorFlow can be clingy with GPU memory. After each iteration, clear it out like so:

```
from keras import backend as K
import gc
# After each iteration:
K.clear_session()
gc.collect()
```

This can also help since, in your grid search, each combination of hyperparameters might be creating a new instance of the model.

Using mixed precision:
This can save memory and speed things up. Set a policy at the top of your code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision
mixed_precision.set_policy(mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16'))
```

And in your last activation layer in the model use dtype='float32' for stability.
e.g.

```
tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax', dtype='float32')
```

You could also try pipelining the dataset. This makes data loading more efficient.

```
### Convert to TF dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
### Fitting the model
vae.fit(train_dataset, epochs=best_epochs, validation_data=val_dataset, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to put clear_session? There is no loop in my code

Comment: Hi,
I overlooked that you're using GridSearchCV. The clear_session would ideally be placed at the end of each cross-fold validation fold. To implement my garbage collection suggestion and for more control, you would probably need to iterate over the hyperparam combinations manually.  I can provide an example if you think it would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508844/scikits-gridsearch-and-python-in-general-are-not-freeing-memory suggests that GridSearchCV can be bad at garbage collection.

Comment: Well, of course. But my post relates with GridSearchCV API from sklearn

Comment: Please still consider the mixed point or pipelining suggestions as they may help.
Also, you could batch-feed the data - there's a good example here https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.
You could also try a workaround and make a custom scorer (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) which trains the model, evaluates performance and clears the GPU using K.clear_session and gc.collect() - the custom Scorer can then be passed to the GridSearchCV call - lmk if you need more details